# Plotting bubbles on top of OpenStreetMap in R

Tags: openstreetmap, r, sp

I can plot points on top of OpenStreetMap like this:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(rgdal)

subscr<-data.frame(lat=c(10.1237,10.2161,10.2993),
    lon=c(59.7567,59.7527,59.6863), pop=c(58,12,150))
coordinates(subscr)<-~lat+lon
proj4string(subscr)<-CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
lat <- c(59.7916,59.6563)
lon <- c(10.0937,10.3293)
map <- openmap(c(lat[1],lon[1]),c(lat[2],lon[2]),zoom=10,'osm')
plot(map)
points(spTransform(subscr,osm()))
```

[image]

But I want bubbles with size relative to population, rather than points. So I substitute the `points` function with `bubble` and run:

```
plot(map)
bubble(spTransform(subscr,osm()))
```

Now I get the following:
[image]

This is not what I want, I want the bubbles on top of the OpenStreetMap. What is the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT:** I see that I mixed up lat and lon in the 3rd non-white line. I won't fix this, as that would mess up the answer given by @rcs, and it doesn't affect the functionality, only gives confusing naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bubbles` uses functions from the [lattice](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lattice) package. The `lattice` package is an implementation of Trellis graphics for R, which is based on the `grid` graphics system.

In your example, `plot(map)` creates a plot using the base graphics system. There are ways to combine plots from both systems (e.g. [gridBase](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gridBase)), but the easiest way is to use base graphics commands like `symbols()` or `points()` (with `cex` argument to control the point size) to add the circles:

```
plot(map)
tmp <- as.data.frame(spTransform(subscr, osm()))
symbols(y = tmp$lon, x = tmp$lat, circles = tmp$pop, add = TRUE,
        inches = 0.2, bg = "darkgreen")
```

[image: symbols plot]

Another option would be for instance [ggmap](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggmap):

```
library("ggmap")
map <- get_map(location = c(lon[1], lat[2], lon[2], lat[1]),
               maptype = "roadmap", source = "osm", zoom = 11)
p <- ggmap(map) +
     geom_point(data = as.data.frame(subscr), aes(x = lat, y = lon, size=pop),
                colour = "darkgreen") +
     theme_bw()
print(p)
```

[image: ggmap plot]